# Tabulator js .getData() is not working through script but able to in browser console to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, tabulator

I dont seem to have any success retrieving the data. Although i was able to execute table.getData() in the browser console. thanks

```
var table

function generateGrid(){
  table = new Tabulator("#dev-schedule-table", {.......
    })}

generateGrid()

var data = table.getData()
```